# Is there a console command that replicates Alt+[F1..F10] to change terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, console

I'm developing a custom embedded barebones distro.

I have console access over serial to my machine. I would like to control what tty my user sees on their framebuffer. Currently the machine boots and sits at the splash screen while my program writes things to tty0. The user has to press Alt+[F1..F10] to get to the desired terminal but I would prefer they not need to know that command.

I'm willing to install packages but would rather not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NAME
>   chvt - change foreground virtual terminal
>
> SYNOPSIS
>   chvt N
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   The command chvt N makes /dev/ttyN the foreground terminal. (The corresponding screen is created if it did not exist yet. To get rid of unused VTs, use deallocvt(1).) The key combination (Ctrl-)LeftAlt-FN (with N in the range 1-12) usually has a similar effect.